# hibernate and c3p0 PooledConnection don't renew connection after database reboot

Tags: java, hibernate, connection, c3p0

I'm using hibernate with c3p0, and as soon as the database is restarted, the application is broken with this error:

```
[warn] [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection] [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
[warn] [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection] [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection ] which will not be reported to listeners!: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
```

at `TypedQuery.getSingleResult()`.

I have to restart the application to fix it.

Yet, the `EntityManager` is a singleton Bean created this way:

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass(driverClassName);
cpds.setJdbcUrl(url);
cpds.setUser(user);
cpds.setPassword(password);
cpds.setPreferredTestQuery("SELECT 1 FROM dual");
cpds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(20);
cpds.setInitialPoolSize(0);
cpds.setMinPoolSize(0);
cpds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
cpds.setTestConnectionOnCheckin(true);

entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(cpds);
```

I don't understand why the connections are never replaced by the pool after the reboot of the database.

Would anyone know how if there is something wrong with the way I'm using c3p0 ?

Comment: It looks like your application is holding Connections open, rather than checking them out as needed and promptly `close()`ing them. Thre's nothing c3p0 can do to refresh a Connection if a client doesn't check the broken Connection back in.

Comment: Yes, but I thought it was the purpose of a connection pool, to let a pool of connections open and ready to be used by hibernate.

Comment: The Connection pool maintains a pool of open Connections. Your application should not: It should acquire Connections as needed, and then immediately "close" them. (Connections acquired from the pool are not in fact closed, they are checked back into the pool.) If your application holds Connections open, there is nothing the pool can do to help you maintain them.

Comment: Thank you, I understand better what you mean. the repositories simply use the entitymanager and never deal with connections directly so it's Hibernate which manages them. Do you suggest it's a problem of configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was not due to c3Pà nor Hibernate.

The bean in error was not managed by Spring, so it explicitly created a new c3p0 `DataSource` at initialization, and didn't use the common c3p0 `DataSource`.

The common `DataSource` was visible with JMX, but not the other one, which means, I think, that the latter was simply **no longer existing**. This is confirmed by the fact that controllers using the common c3p0 `DataSource` still work after database reboot, and the error was only thrown by the bean with dedicated `DataSource`.

Just to finish the story, I solved my problem by reinitializing the dedicated c3p0 `DataSource` in the bean, if an Exception is thrown.